# Organic groups & views

Tags: views, organic-groups

So... I created a few groups and a new content-type. The problem is that I don't know how to display content linked to a certain group using a path like: "/[-content-type]/[group-name] (using views, of course). As far as I know it has something to do with contextual filters, but that's where my knowledge ends.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

take some time and watch these very informative new videos: [Modules Unraveled](http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups) Kudos to Brian Lewis aka [bjlewis2](http://drupal.org/user/223774)